# Outliers en DataFrame. Identificación por rango intercuartílico

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

tengo el siguiente código en python, y me está dando error. Estoy tratando de identificar los valorres outlierS usando el rango intercuartílico y luego comprobando en un diagrama de cajas si se eliminaron.
Tengo el siguiente código:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Calculo el Q1 de ambas variables:
Q1_Anno2016 = np.quantile(df_copy2['Anno2016'], 0.25)
Q1_Anno2014 = np.quantile(df_copy2['Anno2014'], 0.25)
# Calculo el Q3 de ambas variables:
Q3_Anno2016 = np.quantile(df_copy2['Anno2016'], 0.75)
Q3_Anno2014 = np.quantile(df_copy2['Anno2014'], 0.75)
# Caluclo el IQR de ambas variables:
IQR_Anno2016 = Q3_Anno2016 - Q1_Anno2016
IQR_Anno2014 = Q3_Anno2014 - Q1_Anno2014
# Fijo los límites superior e inferior para determinar los outliers (serán aquellos que estén fuera de este rango):
#Límite inferior de ambas variables:
inferior_Anno2016 = Q1_Anno2016 - 1.5 * IQR_Anno2016
inferior_Anno2014 = Q1_Anno2014 - 1.5 * IQR_Anno2014
#Límite superior de ambas variables:
superior_Anno2016 = Q3_Anno2016 + 1.5 * IQR_Anno2016
superior_Anno2014 = Q3_Anno2014 + 1.5 * IQR_Anno2014
# Borro los outliers que esté por debajo del límite inferior:
df_copy2 = df_copy2.drop(df_copy2[df_copy2['Anno2016'] < inferior_Anno2016].index)  # Variable 'Anno2016'
df_copy2 = df_copy2.drop(df_copy2[df_copy2['Anno2014'] < inferior_Anno2014].index)  # Variable 'Anno2014'
# Borro los outliers que esté por encima del límite superior:
df_copy2 = df_copy2.drop(df_copy2[df_copy2['Anno2016'] > superior_Anno2016].index)  # Variable 'Anno2016'
df_copy2 = df_copy2.drop(df_copy2[df_copy2['Anno2014'] > superior_Anno2014].index)  # Variable 'Anno2014'
# Comprueba con un diagrama de cajas si se han eliminado:
plt.boxplot([df_copy2['Anno2016'], df_copy2['Anno2014']], vert=True) 
plt.xticks([1, 2], ['Anno2016', 'Anno2014']) 
plt.title('COMPROBACIÓN EXISTENCIA OUTLIERS')
plt.show()
```

e arroja el siguiente error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_13652\3561135640.py in <module>
      7 
      8 # Calculo el Q1 de ambas variables:
----> 9 Q1_Anno2016 = np.quantile(df_copy2['Anno2016'], 0.25)
     10 Q1_Anno2014 = np.quantile(df_copy2['Anno2014'], 0.25)
     11 

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

¿Me pueden ayudar por favor?

Comment: tu codigo en la linea 3 usa la variable `df_copy2`  pero esta variable no esta declarada en ningun sitio

Answer (score 2):

Parece que hay valores vacios (NaN) por eso el error `'NoneType'`

Hay dos opciones:

- Quitar los valores faltantes con `.dropna()`
- Rellenar los valores con `.fillna()` ya sea con 0 o con otro numero (el promedio es una opcion en caso que no se quieran quitar los valores pero tampoco afectar la integridad de los datos)

Espero que sea de ayuda.

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Eso era. Ya está solucionado

Answer (score 0):

Usa [`nanquantile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nanquantile.html#numpy-nanquantile) para calcular el cuantil ignorando los valores nulos, tambien puedes reemplazar los valores nulos usando `df_copy2['Anno2016'].fillna(numpy.nan)` y despues `numpy.nanquantile(df_copy2['Anno2016'])`, [publicacion relacionada](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52171333/does-the-quantile-function-in-pandas-ignore-nan#:%7E:text=Yes.%20pd.quantile%20%28%29%20will%20ignore%20NaN%20values%20when,the%20specified%20axis%2C%20while%20ignoring%20nan%20values%20%5Bsource%5D.).